# trigger check for updates button with powershell?

Tags: powershell, updates

how can i trigger with PowerShell " check for updates and  check online for updates from Microsoft Updates" button so it changes also "last checked date" when i run the PowerShell command ?
we use WUFB to patch our devices and some of them are not installing updates unless i press on that button .
i tried to run wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow but it is not doing the job .
i also tried Invoke-WUInstall with no success .
i have found some near answers but I still can't do what I want.

Comment: You need UI Automation if you really can't find another way. Please add a screenshot of the window in question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.